# Using javax.validation with Tomcat7

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to get javax.validation working on Tomcat 7.

Ive got in my WEB_INF/lib: hibernate-validator-4.3.0 as well as slf4j-api-1.7.1 and slf4j-simple-1.7.1.

When I run my code, the validation is just ignored! Its all working fine on glassfish, has anyone else had this problem?

Cheers!
NFV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `validation-api.jar` as well. It contains the Bean Validation API including the bootstrapping classes (*javax.validation.Validation*).

Perhaps you downloaded the loose JAR files instead of the [distribution bundle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/). You can download the currently latest 4.3.0 release as zip [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.3.0.Final/hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final-dist.zip/download). It contains all the files you need to drop in `/WEB-INF/lib`. After extracting the zip, you can find the `validation-api.jar` in the `/lib/required` folder.

Comment: Yep that has fixed the problem, I also needed the jboss-logging jar and they are both in the lib/required directory. Thanks for your help!